# Styling complicated tables on mobile - without bootstrap

Tags: css, mobile, html-table

I need help with CSS responsive styling for two tables.
Generally I use Wordpress with a strong emphasis on the non-programmer user being able to easily edit the page. I also use the theme without bootstrap :(

I want to get mobile look as below, without changing desktop one.

[image]

[image]

```
                 table,head,tbody,th,td,tr {
                display: block;
            }
```

Links to JSFidlle:

https://jsfiddle.net/682cqzd1/5/

https://jsfiddle.net/24gqc064/

Comment: paste the code here rather than pasting JSfiddle link.

Comment: yeah, but it's a lot of code :(

Comment: (1) If the code is too big you need to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (2) [Grid layout](https://gridbyexample.com/learn/) was built with this use case in mind. Try it instead of tables if the browsers you're targeting [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) it. (3) If not, you'll probably have to resort to a javascript-y solution that reparents some elements.